# Для чего в ui-файле, созданном в Qt Designer, создается метод retranslateUi?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, retranslateui

Я создал **`ui-файл`** в *Qt Designer* и конвертировал его в *python-файл*. 
Когда пытался разобрать получившийся код, наткнулся на метод `retranslateUi()`.

Вот весь код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(596, 575)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 256, 471))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.ButtonBrowse = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ButtonBrowse.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 500, 75, 23))
        self.ButtonBrowse.setObjectName("ButtonBrowse")
        self.ButtonPlay = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ButtonPlay.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 20, 75, 23))
        self.ButtonPlay.setObjectName("ButtonPlay")
        self.ButtonStop = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ButtonStop.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 20, 75, 23))
        self.ButtonStop.setObjectName("ButtonStop")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 596, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):  #ИНТЕРЕСУЮЩИЙ МЕНЯ МЕТОД
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.ButtonBrowse.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Browse"))
        self.ButtonPlay.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Play"))
        self.ButtonStop.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stop"))
```

---

Пожалуйста, подскажите, для чего нужен этот метод, и как избежать его использования? Имеет ли это смысл?

Comment: А переводы приложения будут?

Comment: @eri  Не обязательно использовать Qt Designer, для динамического переключения языков (переводов) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53349623/how-to-change-languagestranslations-dynamically-on-pyqt5

Comment: В QT Designer у каждого элемента в панели Property снимите галку translateble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В классе `Ui_MainWindow` создаются два метода, setupUi и retranslateUi.

`setupUi` создает объекты виджета в соответствующих контейнерах и присваивает им правильные имена объектов.

`retranslateUi` устанавливает текст и заголовки виджетов.

## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

Я бы вам не советовал сильно рассматривать код сгенерированный `Qt Designer`.
Вы можете загрузить в приложение `файл.ui` напрямую, без конвертации 
и все будет работать.

Теперь посмотрите `файл.ui` - зачем в нем разбираться?

Я бы рекомендовал **НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯТЬ** код, сгенерированный Qt Designer.

Относитесь к данному файлу как к файлу ресурсов, например как к изображению.

Comment: Я не хотел изначально пользоваться Qt Designer - он показался мне неудобным. Я просто хотел понять некоторые вещи и писать GUI вручную

Comment: @MAXIM045 ваш подход, правильный. Вы найдете много правильных вещей для понимания. И правда состоит в том, что не все вещи можно сделать в Qt Designer.

Comment: @MAXIM045 используй наследование